# Cannot access the CuDv object class in the device configuration database

Tags: aix

While trying to configure the IOCP IBM AIX parameter from “defined” to “available” (following the instructions on https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AXDBI/pre_install.htm#AXDBI7634) by running the command `sudo smitty iocp`, I am getting the following errors while trying to save the modification:

> chdev: 0514-518 Cannot access the CuDv object class in the device
>           configuration database.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when running the program as sudo, the environment is not exported, and in particular the variable `ODMDIR` is not set. Once this variable is exported to its default value in a root shell, everything runs correctly:

```
# export ODMDIR=/etc/objrepos
# smitty iocp
```